# Identity impersonate oledb connection in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a issue, In my application I am trying to upload excel data using OLEDB connection.
My code

```
                if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                {
                    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }
                else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                {
                    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }

                //  Create OleDB Connection and OleDb Command

                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dtExcelRecords = new DataTable();


                con.Open();
```

is working fine when I am using

```
<identity impersonate="false"/>
```

But when I am using

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\accountname" password="*****"/>
```

The OLEDB connection throwing error, unspecified error.

Can someone please help me.

Thanks

Gulrej

Comment: Did you the solution to this problem. If we use administrator account in impersonate it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You may want to provide more details about your solution. The impersonated user might not have access to the file.

Impersonation issues are versatile and without knowing your specific configuration it will be hard to help.

Also does the failure happens when you access the server locally or remotely. If it succeeds locally but fails remotely, you may want to assign SPN to the ASP.NET App pool user account for your application.

Check out this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

Comment: The failure is happening in the local system only. I have given full permission to the impersonated user to the folder where my source code is, and full access to the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder also.

Comment: Can you catch the exception being thrown? this would help going understand your problem.